# Supervisor VS CronJobs

Tags: php, laravel-4, cron, supervisord, cron-task

I have to run a laravel command `php artisan queue:work --daemon` to run jobs stored on Beanstalkd queues.

I have come across two possible solutions:

- Run commands using Supervisord: `Register a command in the config files of Supervisord and start it.`
- Run commands using CronJobs: `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/laravelProj/artisan queue:work  --daemon --tries=3`

Can someone please explain what way should I go and what would be the best for performance enhancement.

Answer (score 9):

There is one main advantage of Supervisor that the task you set there is working constantly. This mean that when the proces will finish the new one will starts immediately.

*Crontab* runs every process for a minutue minimum! So if you have a task like `queue:work` is much better to use *Supervisor* over *Crontab*.

Answer (score 3):

Never Ever use `CronJobs` for this executing your queues. There are **few differences** between `CronJobs` and `Superviser`

1. In `CronJobs` you have to set time for executing `php artisan queue:work` and lets suppose you set time for `CronJob` to run every
   5 minutes then even if your current process is finished after 2
   minutes, then the new process will start executing after 5 minutes
   because you set the time for `cronjob` to run after 5 minutes, but
   in `Superviser` when your current process is finished it will
   immediately start new process
2. Second and most important reason why you shouldn't use cronjob for
   executing your queues is, It can **suck all your memory** and
   you will be seeing a lot of unwanted thing happening to your live
   site, because let's suppose you run a process which takes 5 minutes
   to execute and you set time for cronjob to run after 1 minutes then
   after every one minute it will execute command `php aritisan queue:work`. It won't wait to finish previous process and it will
   exhust all your resources, but in Superviser you can limit that how
   many process can run at a time and if processes reached to their
   limit `Superviser` will wait to finish previous processes